# ScriptObjectMirror member to JSON string

Tags: java, json, parsing, tostring, nashorn

I have ScriptObjectMirror object from jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.
I get a JSON node using:

```
Object clientDataNode = scriptObjectMirror.getMember("clientData");
```

How to convert clientDataNode to String to obtain sth like this:

```
  "clientData": {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "age": 22
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I just converted clientData node to string property using javascript method

```
JSON.stringify(clientData)
```

with Nashorn engine
and then obtain it this way, cause it's no longer a member:

```
String jsonClientData = (String) scriptObjectMirror.get("clientData");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use x-stream api , see http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.